# Using view animations in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

Consider I have something like :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
>
    <rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="10"
    android:duration="200" >

    <rotate
    android:fromDegrees="20"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:duration="200" 
    android:fillBefore="false" 
    android:fillEnabled="true">
</set>
```

Here I wish to apply second rotate after 200 ms time (on end result of 1st rotate). But in result, I see that android:fromDegrees (2nd rotate) is applied even before 200 ms as a default 20 degree rotation for first 200ms. I expect the entire block to take effect only after 200 ms. How do I overcome this ?

Also is there any thumb rule to understand 
android:fromDegrees,
android:toDegrees
Since it can take negative values as well as values like 0-20 or 20-0.
How do we interpret these values correctly ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this](http://androidsurya.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-image-animation-example.html)

Comment: can you post your full xml file? the one above is not valid, so it is hard for me to tell where you are having your issue.

Comment: @MeMe Edited the XML please point out the fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured that code snippet in the question is behaving exactly how I expected with only one unwanted result. The second rotation actually starts only after first one is done. The problem here is that :

```
android:fromDegrees="20"
```

from second rotation block is applied to end result of first rotation. Which is what supposed to happen if you want the geometry to rotate from 20 to 0 degrees. Since I wanted to use the end result of first rotation block, I replaced

```
android:fromDegrees="20"
android:toDegrees="0"
```

with

```
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="-20"
```

So output is as per expectation.

Answer (score 0):

create two animations. that is one that should first take place and the  other after 200ms. Add an animation listener to the first animation, and it would call `onAnimationEnd` method when the animation stops, in that method, start the other animation

First Animation file

```
<rotate
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="10"
android:duration="200" >
```

Second Animation file

```
<rotate
android:fromDegrees="20"
android:toDegrees="0"
android:startOffset="200"
android:duration="200" 
android:fillBefore="false" 
android:fillEnabled="true">
```

set :

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
      public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim)
      {
      };
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim)
      {
      };
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)
      {
           layout.startAnimation(the second animation here);
      };
});
```

**EDIT**:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="true"
     android:fillAfter="true">
```

**EDIT 2:**
by default in set the ordering is `together`
change it to `sequentially` and check the animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="true"
     android:fillAfter="true"
   android:ordering="sequentially">
```

Comment: I need to acheive the result using XML ONLY

Comment: try adding share interpolator to the set, @maverick9888 check the edit please

Comment: @maverick9888 check the second edit too if it works for u in the XML

Comment: Sorry for replying late. The changes you have suggested are not working. I still can see the second rotate block being applied in first 200 ms.

Comment: thn in that case, you might have to read the android docs incase theres something missin